# How can I go about sorting a non-array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to .sort() companyName, but since it's not an array, I can't seem to do it. I've tried pushing  companyName to an array, but that gives me multiple arrays which is also not good. How can I go about sorting companyName or creating a singular array that I can sort?

```
var orphanGroupId = this.config.get('orphanFeedbackGroup').id;
      var pushOptions = _.chain(data).filter(function (d) {
        return d.status === 'active' && d._id !== orphanGroupId;
      }).map(function (d) {
        var _id = d._id,
            companyName = d.companyName;
        return {
          name: companyName,
          groupId: _id
        };
      }).value();
      return pushOptions;
    };
```

Comment: It appears you expect us to know what you're manipulating. What's `companyName`? What's `data`? What do you have and what do you want to obtain?

Comment: please include the data you're processing in its original form

Comment: let companyArray = company.name.split("")

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split() method available to strings.

```js
const strToArray = (str)=>{
  if(typeof(str)=='string'){
  return str.split("")
  }
  
}

console.log(strToArray('walmart'))
```